# My html(ejs) is completely ignoring my css file

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, ejs

I'm developing my app from the backend side. My page is supposed load the css locally. I'm using nodejs, express.js, and ejs(for my pages) - The MEN/MEAN stack.

```
<link href="../public/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I'm 100% sure the link is correct since VS Code allows you the check, but I've gotten an error when loading the page up. The error: "The resource from “http://localhost:3000/public/stylesheets/style.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)"

The CSS works fine when I use the style tag instead. What's going on here?

Comment: The server seems to think the CSS file is a HTML file. If you load only the css file at http://localhost:3000/public/stylesheets/style.css into a browser, what file type does the browser report?

Comment: actually i answered the question below

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I solved it. The issue is with Express, it changes the "text/css" part to "text/html". A quick easy workaround would be to remove the "rel=stylesheet" but that can produce mixed results. The best thing is to use `app.use(express.static("public"))` - this will let express know that the public folder is for styles and scripts.

The link now should look like `<link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell express that you have a static assets that you parked all on public folder.

```
app.use(express.static("public"))
```

To know more express magic, follow this github repo.
https://github.com/sagormax/node-admin/